# Mostrar arreglo de objetos Json sin el Id_Persona

Tags: json, array

Hola amigos espero me puedan ayudar he podido llenar mi grid(jqxGrid) dinamicamente con el siguiente código.

```
 for (i in valores[0]) {
               datafields.push({ name: i });
               columns.push({ text: i, datafield: i, width: 200 });                 
           }
```

Donde valores es mi arreglo json, datafields y columns son arreglos.

Lamentablemente también me muestra el id_Persona en el grid por lo que no quiero que este se muestre.

Alguien sabe como hacer eso. De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola comunidad gracias por su ayuda pero ya lo he resuelto aqui dejo el codigo por si a alguien le sirve.

```
           for (j = 1; j < columns.length; j++) {                   
               columnsArray.push(columns[j]);
           }
```